# Laravel how to get all values with where condition

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, model-view-controller, eloquent

this code now takes all matches. I need to take only where home_team_score and away_team_score is not null:

```
$matches = Match::with('score', 'homeTeam', 'awayTeam')->
        where('league_id', '=', $league->id)->get();

    foreach ($matches as $match) {

        $homeTeamScore = $match->score->home_team_score;
        $awayTeamScore = $match->score->away_team_score;
```

Help here with where condition.

Comment: have you looked into using `whereHas` to query the existence of a condition of the relationship? https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need `whereHas` to constrain query to include only the matches where the home_team_score and away_team_score are not null.

```php
$matches = Match::with('score', 'homeTeam', 'awayTeam')
    ->whereHas('score', function($query){
        $query->whereNotNull('home_team_score')
            ->whereNotNull('away_team_score');
    })
    ->where('league_id', '=', $league->id)
    ->get();
```